# htaccess if file does not exist in a folder then redirect to a static page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a folder named "car". In this folder there are lots of files.
For example:

```
 mercedes.php
 audi.php
 bmw.php
```

With the following rewriterule, I can open any page in the "car" folder without adding the file extension. So I can only open the page with car / mercedes instead of car / mercedes.php.

```
 RewriteRule ^car/([^\.]+)$ /car/$1.php?&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

This works, but now I am looking for an additional rule if a file does not exist in this folder -> redirect to default.php

Maybe that way?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/???\.(html|php) !-f
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/car/default.php [R=302]
```

Any idea?
Maybe it does not work, because of my first rule?

Comment: if not exist only in this folder right?

Comment: right! only in folder "car"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for `/car/` directory :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^car/(.*)$   /car/default.php? [R=302]
```

Test it , if it is Ok, change `302` to `301` to get permanent redirection

**Moreover :** Apache by default discard query string but if you want query string to appended you could use `[QSA]` flag unless you want to add spacial query string.

Also , you may noticed that i added  `?` after `default.php` it is only to omit query string when wrong request.